# Should I error-check Close() on a response body?

Tags: go

The docs for [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) have the following example:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Printf("%s", body)
```

[`Close`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Closer) returns an `error`, but it is not checked. Is there something I'm missing here? The importance of checking every error is frequently emphasized in go, but I see this `defer resp.Body.Close()` pattern a lot with no error checks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two things to consider: What would you do with it if you checked it and there was an error? And, what would the side-effects be if there was an error?

In most cases, for closing a response body, the answer to both questions is... absolutely nothing. If there's nothing you'd do if there was an error and the error has no appreciable impact, there's no reason to check it.

Also note that `Close()` returns an error in order to fulfill the `io.Closer` interface; the function doesn't necessarily return an error. You'd need to check the source to know for sure if it has an error case.

Comment: @rcorre, while I'm with Adrian on this, note that everything stated applies only to bodies of HTTP responses—don't blindly apply this to everything! In particular, always check possible errors from `Close()` called on files opened for writing! For an explanation, read [the `open(2)` manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/close.2.en.html#Dealing_with_error_returns_from_close%28%29).

Comment: I'd also add that I habitually put the `// ignoring error` at the end of the same line such statement appears on—to provide a clear hint about the intended behaviour to the next programmer.

Comment: I wouldn't say it only applies to HTTP response bodies - my answer was to assess the specific case and use your best judgement, which I think is pretty generally applicable advice.

Answer (score 21):

This is a downside of using `defer`

It would be advised, as a responsible developer, that you check for all possible error prone points, and handle them as gracefully as you can.

Here are some of the options you can choose in handling this situation:

#### Option #1

Do not use `defer`, instead manually call close once you're done with the response's body and simply check for errors then.

#### Option #2

Create an anonymous function that wraps the closing and error checking code. Something like this:

```
defer func() {
    err := resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}()
```

> Avoid using `panics` in your programs. Try to handle the errors gracefully by doing something or at least logging the error.

---

[Additional information can be found here.](http://www.blevesearch.com/news/Deferred-Cleanup,-Checking-Errors,-and-Potential-Problems/)

Comment: Sorry I know this is a bit old but anyway. The question here is how are you gonna handle the error: you already received the response and it is successful. If error happened during Close should you drop the successful response and throw error? Or should you drop error and proceed with success result? I assume this was the initial question.

Comment: See my (downvoted) answer, it actually handles the error.

Answer (score 5):

To add to @Mihailo option #2, call it option #2.1
Define function `dclose()` like so:

```
func dclose(c io.Closer) {
    if err := c.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

use like so:

```
defer dclose(resp.Body)
```

Also in your code the check for `err!=nil` can declare:

```
func errcheck(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

then use:

```
errcheck(err)
```

then your code becomes:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
errcheck(err)
defer dclose(resp.Body)

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
errcheck(err)

fmt.Printf("%s", string(body))
```

IMHO a little cleaner perhaps? But I'll wait for the `go` aficionado's to correct me and highlight drawbacks.

EDIT

Thanks! @RayfenWindspear

Do replace `log.Fatal(err)` with `log.Println(err)` to avoid unnecessary panic.

EDIT2

`dclose()` to avoid confusion with go `close()`

Have fun!

Comment: This sort of thing is great for simple error cases. It's especially useful for cleaning up playground examples. Many times in production though, each error is often handled differently, which could clutter the namespace with `errcheckJSON` or `errcheck1` (probably not the case with `Close` though). Not dinging on your answer, but just noting the limitations of the general error case. Seems good to me for `Close`, though I would use something more like this https://play.golang.org/p/nzGTFe81g_ instead of causing a panic.

Comment: There is a problem: when `err != nil` is true, `errcheck` should log and return, not just log.

Comment: `log.Fatal(err)` in `errcheck` panics so return is not necessary and if you replace `log.Fatal(err)` with `log.Println(err)` then return is implicit. Also comment by RayfenWindspear address the use case (simple playground examples).

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather, `net/http` can't err. However, I would rather assume that `.Close()` can err for any implementation of `io.Closer` than to study the internals.

Below is an example using named returns where defer only sets the returned error if the error would otherwise be nil:

```
func printResponse(url string) (retErr error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        err := resp.Body.Close()
        if err != nil && retErr == nil {
            retErr = err
        }
    }()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", body)
    return nil
}
```